# How to open a file at a specific line and column?

Tags: bash, perl, vim, exec

I'm working on a module which needs to open a file in `vim` at an arbitrary line and column.  I'm doing this via `exec()`, but `vim` is not getting the correct line and column:

If I distill this down a one-liner:

```perl
perl -E "exec(q{vim}, q{+'call cursor(1,3)'}, q{README.md})"
```

This errors with:

```
"README.md" 116L, 3790C
Error detected while processing command line:
E20: Mark not set
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

When `vim` is showing this error, `ps` is showing `vim +'call cursor(1,3)' README.md`, which is the command that I want.  In fact, copy/pasting `vim +'call cursor(1,3)' README.md` into a new terminal window gives me the desired behaviour.

It looks to me like `vim` thinks the line is 116 rather than 1 and that the column is 3790 rather than 3 when the command is run via Perl's `exec()`.

This is Perl 5.26.1, Vim 8.1 and GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bash command

```
vim +'call cursor(1,3)' README.md
```

is no different than

```
vim '+call cursor(1,3)' README.md
```

Both launch `vim` with the following args:

0: `vim`
1: `+call cursor(1,3)`
2: `README.md`

However, you instructed Perl to pass the following args to `vim`:

0: `vim`
1: `+'call cursor(1,3)'`
2: `README.md`

The Perl equivalent of that shell command would be

```
exec('vim', '+call cursor(1,3)', 'README.md')
```